# PDF file empty after outputting with Jersey

Tags: java, pdf, jersey

I am trying to send a PDF file I generated in my server to my client in my Jersey application. The generation goes just fine, I created the file on my local machine and there is no problem with it.

Problem arises when I try to send it by a stream. When I try to read the outputted file, it's completely empty (sometimes, it's just corrupted, same file same code, but the file is corrupeted instead of blank) however, the amount of page is correct, which is really strange. I then tried to use the stream to create a local file, which worked just fine, so I'm pretty sure the problem isn't with what I put in my stream, it's within my method of sending it to the client. I also tried with different, completly normal, pdf, and I have the same problem.

Some code sample

```
@Path("/produiretest/{id}")
@GET
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response rapportStreamTest(@PathParam("id") Long id) throws Exception {
    final StreamingOutput file = manager.produireRapportStreamingTest(id);
    Response.ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "previsualisationFicheSignaletique.pdf");
    return response.build();
}
```

The StreamingOutput implement (even if I think that's correct)

```
StreamingOutput outStream = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream outputStream) {
            try {
                JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
        };
        return outStream;
```

Sample from the response I get when I poke the server, obviously broken.

> %PDF-1.4
>   %����
>   5 0 obj
>   <>stream
>   x���1 ��g
>   ?�����
>   endstream
>   endobj
>   6 0 obj
>   <>]/Intent/Perceptual/Subtype/Image/Height 600/Filter/FlateDecode/Type/XObject/Width 600/SMask 5 0 R/Length 23357/BitsPerComponent 8>>stream
>   x���{pU��>pLB¥E@�� ��Bu8��ܔ!@% �=P�H)j�Ns΀xAD8"IA��$��i�r�Ŋ0@�~������7@B.{��k=k������������I����_"�����nݺu͚5K�.�;w��I��}��aÆ�����ׯw��ݺu�ܹsǎ۷oߪU�f͚5n���뮫W�^bbb||�U?������__
>   ___��!�s�G�O�p8v=DD�6�*֯*��{�����cƌy��G�ao�>U�nݸ���<�C��p�8T0�S���k)""�u�ȑ�7���L���R� (���WIDD�(..޾}{vvvfffZZZӦM=��LoB�P(�EC�P@����""�Ç���ӦM6lX�ػ�
>   PF%EaQ^���""���B����jƌ�
>   jܸ1{�

Don't really go where to go from now, any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a couple of phone calls I've managed to solve my problem that can be broken down in 2 parts :

1) The way our application structure works, our client apps doesn't directly poke the Tomcat server where the backend app is. We have a Node.js server that serves as a dispatcher for request. Apparently there is a problem within the Node that attempts to interpret the stream with the wrong encoding or something. Will have to contact the team that manages the Node.

2) For some reason the Postman Chrome app seems afflicted by the same problem as our Node server. Using the DHC plugin for Chrome for the backend testing fixed my problems.

So I made a mistake to assume the problem was within the server side of the code because Postman and Client-side gave the same problem, while in reality the result is in between and Postman seems to have a problem too. Not quite sure yet, will have to investigate why it works on DHC and not Postman later.